# If statements and picture box values issue

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, picturebox

i'm trying to create a snap game but when it comes to checking if the picture box contains the correct image, it simply just does not work, i've done a bit of research regarding this and implemented the ideas. it does not throw up any sort of error but i just do not receive a increased value when i should. Please have a look at this code and tell me if you know where i'm going wrong.

Attempt 1:

```
  Dim BirdPics() As Image = {My.Resources.Image_1}
If tbxAnimal_Group.Text = "Birds" And BirdPics.Contains(pbxPicture.Image) Then

    CurrentPoints += 1
    lblScore.Text = "Score:" & CurrentPoints
End If
```

Attempt 2

```
     Dim BirdPics() As Image = {My.Resources.Image_1}
If tbxAnimal_Group.Text = "Birds" And pbxPicture Is BirdPics Then

    CurrentPoints += 1
    lblScore.Text = "Score:" & CurrentPoints
End If
```

Comment: You need to track which image each PB holds perhaps using the `.Tag` property (or a variable!).  You cant compare images to one another without laboriously comparing each pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use "BirdPics.Contains"; it does not work like that.

Simple comparisons cannot be made on images.

IF ThisImage = ThatImage THEN ' doesn't necessarily work even though it will compile.

Create a structure or class and store them in a list.

```
Structure gameObjects
 BirdPic as Image
 BirdPicName as string
 Position as Point
End Structure

DIM GamePictures(0) AS gameObjects

SUB Main()

    ' Create a new object
    DIM newObj as New gameObjects
    With newObj
         .BirdPic = Image.FromFile("pics/bluejay.jpg")
         .BirdPicName = "BlueJay"
         .Position = new point(10, 20)
    End With
    AddObject(newObj)




    for index = 0 to gamepictures.count - 1
        If tbxAnimal_Group.Text = "Birds" AND GamePictures(index).BirdPicName = "BlueJay" THEN
            ' Do Something
        End If
    next
END SUB 


Public Sub AddObject(obj as GameObjects)
       DIM thisObjIndex as integer = GamePictures.Count 
       ReDim preserve GamePictures(thisObjIndex + 1)

       GamePictures(thisObjIndex) = obj
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, i'll have to do quite a bit of modification to my code in order for this to work but hopefully it will!

Comment: No problem. Once you start treating everything as an object, life becomes so much simpler. You can store anything in those structures, including sprite locations (AS Point) or sprite bounds (AS Rectangle), sprite animation can be done easily by creating a list(of SpriteImages) inside of a game object and cycling through them using an incremental interval, and so forth.

Comment: Keep in mind, when using a LIST, you cannot modify those objects. They are read-only once they are added. If you need to constantly modify the state of an object in a list, better to use an array like "DIM GamePictures() AS gameObjects" and ReDim Preserve when adding/removing from the array.

Comment: What format/notation would i use to put my pictures in an array?